# What does this nested fcntl do?

Tags: c

I found this code in the book [serious-cryptography-practical-modern-encryption](https://www.nostarch.com/seriouscrypto).

What is nested `fcntl` doing? 
Getting the file descriptor and Ored it with `FD_CLOEXEC`, not clear to me what I going on here.

```
#ifndef O_CLOEXEC 
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
```

Other code omitted for clarity.

Comment: I was thinking the code was unsafe because `fcntl(fd, F_GETFD)` could return an error, but one would expect the other `fcntl` to fail too in that situation.

Comment: Yea, @ikegami I thought so too. It will be best to get the return value from the inner fcntl, check for errors before passing it to the second method.

Comment: @ikegami It is a surprise when he is preaching about secure code and did this. Thanks also for pointing out.

Comment: There's no meaningful way the operation of "get" (or "set", in this case) can fail, and no meaningful way to make forward progress if either operation could. You check for failure when there's a legitimate reason something can fail & a way to handle that situation, not just for its own sake.

Comment: It doesn't get the file descriptor. It gets the file descriptor flags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Getting the file descriptor

No, it gets the **flags** of the file descriptor. See the [`fcntl()` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html). The outer call then sets these flags, with additionally `FD_CLOEXEC` set. This makes sure the file is closed when a function of the `exec()` family is called (i.e. when the process is replaced with a new program image). This is a security measure, it avoids leaking the opened file accidentally to a program you pass control to with `exec*()`.

It's only done when no `O_CLOEXEC` is available, which allows setting this flag already when opening the file.

Comment: Oh ok, The inner `fcntl` will return flags like `O_RDONLY` etc for the `fd`. It makes sense now. But what if we set `FD_CLOEXEC` for the fd directly without a nested call to `fcntl`? will that make any difference?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you mean **without**, you would clear all the other flags -> not what you want.

Comment: Yea I meant that sorry for the error. thanks for the help. Is all clear now. I never knew fcntl overwrites the old flags.

Answer (score 1):

`fcntl(fd, F_GETFD)` is "get file descriptor *flags*" operation and `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, flags)` is "set file descriptor flags".

Thus the overall meaning is "add `FD_CLOEXEC` to the set of the flags".